# JavaFX - using setRowFactory to highlight new rows

Tags: css, javafx, tableview

I am writing a JavaFX app where a series of messages appear in a TableView.  When a new message appears, its row in the table should be highlighted, meaning its background color should be orange or something.  Once the user clicks it, the background color should clear, acknowledging the message was read.  Should be simple.

I've done enough research to realize that I need to use a rowFactory to set or clear a row's background.  But I'm struggling with the mechanics of `setRowFactory()`.  The documentation on Oracle is over my head, and every example I pull up online seems radically different than the last one.

Here's what I have:

```
public class Message {
    private boolean readOnce;
    private int date;
    private String msg;

    public Message(int date, String msg, String msg2){
        this.readOnce = false;
        this.date = date;
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public boolean isReadOnce() {
        return readOnce;
    }
    public void setReadOnce(){
        readOnce = true;
    }
    // ...and more standard getters & setters here...
 }
```

The TableView is set up in the main controller:

```
    @FXML   TableView<Message> messageTable;
    @FXML   TableColumn<Message, Integer>   Col1;
    @FXML   TableColumn<Message, String>    Col2;
    ObservableList<Message> tableItems;

// ...

    // Setting up the Table:
    PropertyValueFactory<Message, Integer> dateProperty = new PropertyValueFactory<Message, Integer>("date");
    PropertyValueFactory<Message, String>  msgProperty  = new PropertyValueFactory<Message, String>("msg");
    Col1.setCellValueFactory( dateProperty );
    Col2.setCellValueFactory( msgProperty );
    messageTable.setItems( tableItems );

    // If we click an item in the table:        messageTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
        if (newSelection != null) {
            System.out.println("Troubleshoot:  You clicked: "+newSelection.getMsg());
            newSelection.setReadOnce(true);
        }
    });
```

And if I want to add a new message to the table, I just add it into the observable list:

```
public void addMsg(int num, String msg){
    tableItems.add(new Message(num, msg));
}
```

So far, pretty easy.  But I'm all thumbs when it comes to the rowFactory:

```
    messageTable.setRowFactory(messageTable -> {
        TableRow<Message> row = new TableRow<>();
        ObjectProperty<Message> opMsg = row.itemProperty();
        Message tmpMsg = opMsg.get();
        if(!tmpMsg.isReadOnce()){
            row.getStyleClass().add("highlight-message");     // defined in CSS
        } else {
            row.getStyleClass().add("clear-message");         // defined in CSS
        }
        return row;
    });
```

To be very honest, I have no idea what I'm doing here.  I understand that the rowFactory takes in the entire table and regenerates each row one-by-one.  What I don't understand is how does the RowFactory code examine each Message in the table and how can I access them?  Originally I thought these line might allow me to see the Message within the row:

```
        TableRow<Message> row = new TableRow<>();
        ObjectProperty<Message> opMsg = row.itemProperty();
        Message tmpMsg = opMsg.get();
```

But when I debug the code, tmpMsg == NULL.  So that's a big fat dead end.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  I've been researching this for about a week, getting absolutely no-where.  Any help anyone can offer is wildly appreciated.

Many thanks,
-RAO

Comment: Can you use JavaFX properties in your `Message` class?

Comment: @James_D Sure, I don't see why not.  In fact, is that helps me, I'm all for it...!

Comment: Actually - Fabian's answer is a simpler approach than the one I had in mind, and makes that redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TableRow`s are created by `TableView` to fill it's viewport and contain `TableCell`s. At the time they are created the `item` property still contains the default value `null`. You could register a listener to that property but usually I prefer overriding the `updateItem` method of a cell.

Also using `PseudoClass` is simpler than using style classes. New items can be assigned to a row; this could result in the same style class being added multiple times and even both style classes could be added to the same cell. `PseudoClass`es however can be switched on/of without the need to take care of removing other classes.

```
final PseudoClass highlightMessage = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("highlight-message");

messageTable.setRowFactory(messageTable -> new TableRow<Message>() {

    {
        selectedProperty().addListener((o, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            if (newVal) {
                Message item = getItem();
                if (item != null) {
                    item.setReadOnce();
                    pseudoClassStateChanged(highlightMessage, false);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Message item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        pseudoClassStateChanged(highlightMessage, item != null && !item.isReadOnce());
    }

});
```

In a CSS stylesheet you could use rules like this:

```css
.table-row-cell:filled {
    /* style for non-highlighted rows */
}

.table-row-cell:filled:highlight-message {
    /* style for highlighted rows */
}
```

Note that this does not allow you to programmatically alter the read state. It updates the state on selecting a cell. You could add a `BooleanProperty` to `Message` or use a `ObservableSet` to store the highlighted messages and update the state of cells from a listener if you need to programmatically update the `readOnce` property. In the latter case you do not need to store a `readOnce` property in the `Message` itself...

Comment: --  EXCELLENT!!!  Wow, that did the trick.  I have a follow-up question, if you don't mind...  I've noticed all the online examples do an Override of updateItem() and then immediately do an "super.updateItem(...) ;"  I assume this means "do updateItem() and then do this extra stuff."  But why is this call necessary?  Many, many thanks  :)

Comment: that previous praise & comment was meant for fabian... not sure why the system scrubbed their name.  Again, many, many thanks  :)

Comment: `TableRow.updateItem` handles updating the `empty` and `item` properties and set the `filled` or `empty` pseudoclasses so you unless you want to do all that yourself you need to do eveything `TableRow.updateItem` would have done plus you custom code...