# Java FX: How to rewrite a RowFactory without an anonymous inner class - Java 8 Compatible

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, tableview

I'm currently getting my project set up to use Java 8.  Due to restrictions this is the current highest version of Java I can run.  When converting to Java down from my previous Java 11 configuration I ran into the following issue:

```
playlistDetailsTable.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<>() {
                                                             ^
  reason: '<>' with anonymous inner classes is not supported in -source 8
    (use -source 9 or higher to enable '<>' with anonymous inner classes)
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class TableRow
```

Here is the current block of code that it is failing on.  This merely higlights a table row iff a playlist has been Retired.

```
        playlistDetailsTable.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Map item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                ObservableList<String> styles = getStyleClass();
                if (item == null ) {
                    setStyle("");
                } else {
                    final String currentPlaylistRow = (String)item.get(PlaylistBreakdownEnum.PLAYLIST.getColName()) ;
                    final String cleanPlaylistString = currentPlaylistRow.replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", "").stripTrailing();
                    if (PlaylistEnum.getEnumByPlaylist(cleanPlaylistString).getRetired()) {
                        getStyleClass().add("retired-row");
                    }
                    else {
                        getStyleClass().removeAll("retired-row");
                        }
                }
            }
        });
```

Does anyone know how to effective go about fixing this?

Comment: [You can't use the diamond operator with anonymous classes in Java 7 or 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200647/why-cant-java-7-diamond-operator-be-used-with-anonymous-classes). Make the type explicit (e.g. `new TableRow<Foo>() { ... }`).

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48979109/javafx-using-setrowfactory-to-highlight-new-rows helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not caused by the use of an anonymous class. The issue is that, [due to reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200647/why-cant-java-7-diamond-operator-be-used-with-anonymous-classes), you cannot use the diamond operator with anonymous classes in Java 7 or 8. That feature wasn't added until Java 9. Since you're using Java 8 you'll have to update your code to make the generic type explicit.

For example, instead of using:

```java
playlistDetailsTable.setTableRow(tv -> new TableRow<>() {
    // custom TableRow implementation
});
```

You have to use:

```java
playlistDetailsTable.setTableRow(tv -> new TableRow<YOUR_TYPE_HERE>() {
    // custom TableRow implementation
});
```

Where you replace `YOUR_TYPE_HERE` with the type used with your `TableView`. In other words, if your `playlistDetailsTable` is a `TableView<Playlist>` then you would use `TableRow<Playlist>`.